# Empty results on LEFT JOIN in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm trying to find users from my database that don't have ANY rows in another table for the previous month, although it looks like my query is correct; I'm getting empty results?

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //Set Payment Dates
        $this->dates = array('1st', '8th', '15th', '25th');

        //Which Month do the figures need submitting as
        $this->monthPrev    = date('F Y', strtotime(date('F Y')." -1 month"));
        $this->currentMonth = date('F Y', strtotime('this month'));
    }

public function getUnreportedQuarterlies()
    {
        $this->db->select('quarterly_figures.month, quarterly_figures.centre, users.name, users.email');
        $this->db->from('quarterly_figures');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.name = quarterly_figures.centre', 'left');
        $this->db->where("quarterly_figures.month", $this->monthPrev);
        $this->db->where("quarterly_figures.centre IS NULL");
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

My database rows look something like so:

**users**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owners_password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `address`, `owners_password`) VALUES
(1, 'Aldridge', 'aldridge@website.co.uk', 'password', '127.0.0.1', 'password');
```

**quarterly_figures**

```
CREATE TABLE `quarterly_figures` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `centre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `direct_debits` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `money_paid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `quarterly_figures` (`id`, `centre`, `month`, `date`, `direct_debits`, `money_paid`) VALUES
(1, 'Rugby', 'January 2019', '2019-01-01', '128', '3519.00');
```

Comment: It's definitely incorrect since you are checking for a null condition in the left table, not the right. Your description is unclear, so I cannot really tell whether you mixed up the sides of the join or just filtering on the wrong table.

Comment: @Shadow raw SQL is where I struggle, I basically just need to retrieve all `users.name` that don't have a row in the `quarterly_figures` table based on the provided `quarterly_figures.month`

Comment: Given the data set above, what should the desired result look like?

Comment: Then you mixed up the order of your tables. Either use a right join or change the order of tables in the join.

Answer (score 1):

The 'user' table has no relation with the 'quarterly_figures' table , If there is no relation returned data is not possible.  you can insert an users.id into  'quarterly_figures' for each input.